# Como mudar linhas de tabelas no R por valores da mesma linha só que de outra coluna

Tags: r

```
   [,1]            [,2]
[1,] "NAO INFORMADO" "1" 
[2,] "2"             "3"
[3,] "NAO INFORMADO" "5" 
[4,] "4"             "1" 
[5,] "NAO INFORMADO" "3" 
[6,] "6"             "5"
```

queria mudar todos os valores não informados pelos valores da coluna 2 da mesma linha

Comment: Olá, Leonardo. Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Sua pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Por favor, edite-a com exemplos de entradas e saídas esperadas.

Answer (score 4):

Seus dados tem um formato bem estranho, pois é uma matriz com texto e números. Provavelmente o ideal seria substituir os `NAO INFORMADO` por `NA`, na leitura dos valores. Da forma atual, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
dados <- read.table(text="NAO INFORMADO, 1 
2,             3
NAO INFORMADO, 5 
4,             1 
NAO INFORMADO, 3 
6,             5", sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dados[dados[,1] == "NAO INFORMADO",1] <- dados[dados[,1] == "NAO INFORMADO",2]

dados
#  V1 V2
#1  1  1
#2  2  3
#3  5  5
#4  4  1
#5  3  3
#6  6  5
```

Mas se fossem `NA`, seria um pouco mais simples:

```
dados[is.na(dados[,1]),1] <- dados[is.na(dados[,1]),2]
```

Note que essa forma considera que seus dados são uma matriz. Também funcionaria se fosse um `data.frame`, mas neste caso seria possível escrever um código um pouco mais elegante.